# Running the pod install in React-native-firebase Messaging

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging".

In Podfile:
RNFBMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`) was resolved to 10.1.1, which depends on
Firebase/Messaging (~> 7.1.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Messaging (~> 7.1.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: It sounds like you are having a dependency mismatch. It will help people help you if you post your Podfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your platform :ios, 'your value' to platform :ios, '10.0' or above
from platform/ios/Podfile file.

It worked for me.